# Creating WP custom post types with custom fields from database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I'm working on a Wordpress website that uses an external system to sell tickets. This ticket system provides a WordPress plugin that automatically creates and updates two new WordPress database tables: events and shows. That's great, but that's all this plugin does.

I have used the Database Browser plugin to test if the database tables created by the ticket system plugin were there and that was the case. I can see all the data there too. So far so good.

I now need to create custom post types (events and shows) with custom fields using the data from these database tables. I've searched, but I can't seem to find out how to create custom post types that pull their data from existing database tables.

Maybe I'm looking at this all wrong. Any help to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

To create custom post refer this http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types

And use this plugin to create custom field http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming you realise that you'll need to write code to query db...there are no plugins to query a db (that i know of).

it also sounds like you are going to duplicate data ie pull data from custom table events and shows, then add to this data to custom fields. i'm not sure this is the best approach.

also, if data in these custom tables change, will it be reflected in your custom fields data?

have i assumed too much? let me know.

To query db, use the wp class [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). I havent really used it but it has enough features to do what you want.

[acf plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) has already been mentioned. [custom post type ui plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) is easy for creating custom post types with no code. it even prints out the actual code for you so you can copy it, place in functions.php, then disable plugin, nice.

Comment: I realize I'll need to write code. But where to start? What I would like is create posts and populate custom fields in these posts with data from these tables. If possible. That way, if the data changes, it should change the posts and the data in the custom fields. Am I right?

Comment: when `shows` and `events` tables get updated, you'll need to update custom fields then, and manually (your own function), unless you get technical and use db [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html). assuming these custom post types are edited/published by a human, i guess you want them to see the `shows` and `events` fields...maybe just display them to poster, and dont add the data to custom fields, then when displaying post, pull from `shows` and `events` table. you wont duplicate data and it will always be up-to-date.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your answer. And I'm having a hard time explaining myself too it seems... Yes, I want these custom post types to be editable by a human. And I want the data to be always up-to-date. But I don't understand how to create the correct custom post types that pull their data directly from the shows and events tables. If that is possible.